# Blender 3.6.2 Normalize weights not working correctly

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

This looks like a random bug - I'll be doing fine, then normalizing stops working and I can't figure out why.
The behavior: Auto-normalize setting on brush stops working, same thing for the Weight paint normalize buttons, and in vertex weights in the side panel.  I end up with the same value in each of the bones on a vert that does not add up to 1.00. Changing a value and clicking normalize changes all the values on a bone.

Comment: There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here have any association with the Blender Foundation.  If you can reliably produce the bug, report it via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.